# Mongoose create multiple objects in a array with partial success

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

There's a method [Model#create](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.create) in a Mongoose to which I can send an array of objects.

```
var items = [{id: 1},{id: 2},{id: 3},{id: 4}];
Model.create(array, function (err, succededItems) {
   ...
});
```

Everything works fine except behavior when some of the objects which I try to create failed to be saved. In this scenario in `err` object I get, there're details about first object which has been failed, and in `succededItems` I get an array of the objects which have been saved.

I doubt is it possible to get in `err` or other way, an array which objects failed to save and reason, why did this happen?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately [Mongoose returns only the first error](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/master/lib/model.js#L1935), so your best option would be to use a combination of promises :

```
Promise
    .all( items.map( item => {
         return Model.create( item ) 
                     .catch( error => ( { error } ) )
    }) )
    .then( items => {

         items.forEach( item => {
             if ( item.error ) {
                console.log( "Item has failed with error", item.error );
             } else {
                console.log( "Item created successfully" );
             }
         } );

    } );
```